# How to calculate factorial in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, factorial

I am new to tensorflow, I am trying to find a function that calculates the n!. 
I saw that one can use the gamma function, which was possible with theano, but did not work for tensorflow.

```py
factorial = theano.tensor.gamma(v)
```

I am using a for loop to multiply number from n to 1, but I assume there is an easier and faster way. I saw functions related to gamma distribution, but couldn't figure out how to calculate the factorial. Would appreciate if one can point me to some documentation.

Here is the way I do it now

```
import tensorflow as tf

factorial = tf.Variable(1, "factorial")
recursion = tf.Variable(1, "recursion")

# calculate factorial
mult = tf.multiply(recursion, factorial)
assign_fact = tf.assign(factorial, mult)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init) 
    for i in range(2,10):
        counter = tf.assign(recursion, tf.constant(i))
        sess.run(counter)
        sess.run(assign_fact)

        print(i,"factorial is", sess.run(factorial))

    sess.close()
```

Output is

```
2 factorial is 2
3 factorial is 6
4 factorial is 24
5 factorial is 120
6 factorial is 720
7 factorial is 5040
8 factorial is 40320
9 factorial is 362880
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: `tf.exp(tf.lgamma(x + 1))`.

[`tf.lgamma`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lgamma) computes the log of the absolute value of Gamma(x) element-wise, so the exponent will give you the raw Gamma(x) value:

```
>>> sess.run(tf.exp(tf.lgamma(5.0)))
24.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean that there is no simple gamma function for tensorflow, and is it better to use exp of lgamma instead of loop multiplication?

Comment: Indeed, I couldn't spot the raw gamma function in tf, it's fairly possible to be added in future versions. Computing with two math ops is certainly faster than the loop, though I think you don't want to compute the factorial for large inputs. Anyway, it's shorter.

Comment: This solution nicely covers many use cases without much fuss, but it will get the incorrect sign for certain intervals of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tf.math.reduce_prod(tf.range(1,x+1))
```